# MongoKitten support for $inc modifier

Tags: mongodb, vapor, mongokitten

I want to update an auto increment field in MongoDB through Vapor and MongoKitten. Not necessarily a unique key.

The goal is to use $inc modifier in order to make it a single atomic operation and get the returned incremented result all in one go.

Is there support for this operation with MongoKitten?

Can I achieve this e.g. by using **findAndUpdate** method?

If yes what would be an example syntax of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With MongoKitten you can use the `findAndUpdate` function on Collection to do this. The input should be a query (unless you want to increment all entities in the collection) and a `with` argument for the update document.

```
// The query used to find the document to increment
let query: Query = "_id" == ...
```

Inside the update Document, you can use the [$inc operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/#up._S_inc) like so:

```
let updateDoc: Document = ["$inc": ["myKey": 1]]
```

This will update the "myKey" by incrementing it by 1

```
let updated = try collection.findAndUpdate(query, with: updateDoc)
```

The `updated` document will contain the document *before* updating, so if `myKey` has a value of 3. It'll be incremented to 4 after this query, but you'll receive the document with the value `3`.

To change this you can change the `returnedDocument` argument (which defaults to `.old`)

```
let updated = try collection.findAndUpdate(query, with: updateDoc, returnedDocument: .new)
```

Finally, if you care about optimisation or just find limiting your returned results in general you should consider adding a projection. [Projections](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/) indicate to the database which fields you are and are not interested in.

You can use it with the `findAndUpdate` to ensure only the relevant field(s) are returned, which is the `myKey` integer value in this example.

```
let updated = try collection.findAndUpdate(query, with: updateDoc, returnedDocument: .new)
```